# ES how does this below field match & Not removing token on particular scenario?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below mapping.

```
"sub":{"type":"text", "analyzer":"stop_analyzer"}
```

I have a query

```
{
"_source":["sub"],
"query": {
   "fuzzy" : { "sub" : "Thr" }
}
}
```

Analyzer:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer":{
            "stop_analyzer":{
                "tokenizer":"lowercase",
                "filter":["synonym_graph","stop_el_filter"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "stop_el_filter": {
                "type":       "stop",
                "stopwords":  "_english_"
            },
            "synonym_graph" : {
                    "type" : "synonym_graph",
                    "lenient": true,
                    "synonyms" : [
                        "americas, us, usa, u.s.a, america => america",
                        "americas-us public sector, america ps, ps america, ps usa => ps"
                    ]
                }
        }
    }
}
```

How does the below String matches:

(USER_TRIGGERED (ALL:MAINT=8hr ARL of Nodes 02-A/B))

Analyse API provides the below tokens:

```
 "token": "user"
 "token": "triggered"
 "token": "all"
 "token": "maint",
 "token": "hr"
 "token": "arl"
 "token": "nodes"
 "token": "b"
```

Why `Thr` is matching this doc? When I analyse `Thr` it results `thr`.

Is it because of fuzzy removes `t` to match `hr`? - Yes, I think I am correct.

And

is there any way not to remove that `A` from `A/B` - not considering as a stop word in particular cases [not tokenise when `A` is not accompanied by space]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thr` is matching your doc because of the `fuzzy` query which allows a distance of 1 character on that word length. Hence, `fuzzy(Thr)` matches the `hr` token.

Regarding your second question, `A` is removed because it is an english stop word and you're using the `stop` token filter. So if you remove it, the `A` will be indexed as well

Comment: I want A not to be removed when A is in A/B but want to be removed when A is alone.

Comment: You should maybe try the [classic tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-classic-tokenizer.html) instead of lowercase (and add a lowercase token filter instead)

Comment: I will try this and let you know @Val

Comment: This classic tokeniser is misleading in some places. I will add another question/update this soon